# Golang - Unable to get results from pipped Windows command

Tags: go, cmd, command, pipe

I am struggling to get the output for a Windows command that has a pipe in it. Here is the command:

> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"

Here is the code:

```
c1 := exec.Command("systeminfo")
c2 := exec.Command("findstr", "/B", `/C:"OS Name"`)

r, w := io.Pipe()
c1.Stdout = w
c2.Stdin = r

var b2 bytes.Buffer
c2.Stdout = &b2

c1.Start()
c2.Start()
c1.Wait()
w.Close()
c2.Wait()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, &b2)
fmt.Println(b2)
```

> Output: []

If I copy/paste the command in cmd, it will return results. Not sure why I can't get that reflected in my Go programme. I tried several variants, including the addition of "cmd", "/C" in the first command but no success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `io.Copy` to no redirect to STDOUT and print the content of the buffer.

```golang
    systemCmd := exec.Command("systeminfo")
    findCmd := exec.Command("findstr", "/B", "/C:OS Name")

    reader, writer := io.Pipe()
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    systemCmd.Stdout = writer
    findCmd.Stdin = reader
    findCmd.Stdout = buf
    systemCmd.Start()
    findCmd.Start()
    systemCmd.Wait()
    writer.Close()
    findCmd.Wait()
    reader.Close()

    fmt.Println(">>" + buf.String())
```

ie:

```golang
PS C:\Users\user\Documents> go run .\main.go
>>OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
```

Comment: Thank you very much elulcao, it works! Could you please explain why the backticks (with double quotes inside) are not working?

Comment: @Dlionis
From `exec.go`:

On Windows, processes receive the whole command line as a single string
and do their own parsing.

Backticks will not escape double quotes and hence it is passed as part of the single string to be parsed, the exec parser seems to be parsing based on this.